# How can I change "selected" field on datetime?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm using a date picker on Tizen (Wearable):

```
Evas_Object* datetime = elm_datetime_add(layout);
Evas_Object* circle_datetime = eext_circle_object_datetime_add(datetime, circlesurface);
elm_object_style_set(datetime, "datepicker/circle");
```

This results a layout like this:

[image]

By default, year has been selected, so I can immediately change it with the rotary.

**I wish the day field to be selected by default.**

How can I reach this?

What I've found is an ancient [source](https://review.tizen.org/git/?p=framework/uifw/efl-ext.git;a=blob;f=wearable/src/lib/circle/efl_extension_circle_object_datetime.c;h=06f92498d82e71c4be6cd1fc1c01df606672b44d;hb=refs/heads/tizen_2.4) of Tizen. In this file, at the bottom, there is a notation of a "FIXME":

> FIXME(150420) : After deciding how to support current types to
> application developer, we will define these APIs' name and parameters.

And there is also a function:

```
EAPI void
eext_circle_object_datetime_selected_field_type_set(Evas_Object *obj, Elm_Datetime_Field_Type type)
```

I could fire a touch event on my desired part, but I don't know where is the `datepicker/circle` EDC source file.

Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is no API for your requirement.

But you can do that with below way.

1. Gets day object in datetime layout

   Evas_Object *day_obj = elm_object_part_content_get(datetime, "field2");
2. Set focus to given object

   elm_object_focus_set(day_obj, true);

Answer (score 0):

You can change DateTime field order as below API.

```
elm_datetime_format_set(datetime, "%d%b%Y");
```

Please refer below page for more detail.

https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/mobile/component-datetime/

Comment: I don't want to change the order, only the focus :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh i see.https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/2.3.2/group__Focus.html#gad2e04b8263454b9186959375f58a9660